# How to remove buttons that were procedurally generated

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I generate a number of buttons within my winform based on what is in a list this works fine, however I need to reset the form back to having none of the new buttons existing.

The button generating code is:

```
private int importButtonFactory()
        {
            int numberOfButtons = 0;

            int top = 70;
            int left = 12;

            foreach (Import import in ImportList)
            {
                Button importButton = new Button();
                importButton.Left = left;
                importButton.Top = top;
                importButton.Width = 220;
                this.Controls.Add(importButton);
                top += importButton.Height + 2;
                numberOfButtons++;
                importButton.Text = import.Mapping;
                importButton.Click += (object sndr, EventArgs c_args) => openFile_Click(import.Path);
            }

            return numberOfButtons;
        }
```

I have tried following within a separate function:

`Controls.Remove(importButton);`

But I get the error: `"The name 'importButton' does not exist in the current context"`

Comment: Yes and that's cause the control instance declared inside a different function.

Comment: best store references in a class level List<Button> and delete them from those references, not forgetting the references themselves!

Comment: Probably you are using incorrect reference. You can assign name to those buttons and try to find and remove them by name. Also you can keep a reference of them in a list and then remove them using that reference.

Comment: When creating controls dynmically you need to set the `Name` property to a good name. If you don't they may all get the same name or none at all! Add a counter to the name, just as the designer does, then you can access it by the controls indexer and that Name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and that's cause the control instance declared inside a different function. You can create a `List<Button>` and have them clear later like

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();



private int importButtonFactory()
        {
            int numberOfButtons = 0;

            foreach (Import import in ImportList)
            {
                Button importButton = new Button();
                ....


               buttonList.Add(importButton);
         }
```

In your other method you can access the list and remove them

Comment: A great thanks, I wasn't sure if there was a way to remove them all at once due to them all sharing a name, but this was works wonderfully.